# Commit to folder on Git

Tags: git, github

I have created 2 folders on git as shown below.

[image]

Now I want to commit 2 solutions into those folders.When I try to commit the first one (Client) it shows below error.Can you tell me how to do that ? 
How can I give this arbitrary Url ?

[image]

**Error :**

[image]

Comment: That is not how Git works. None of what you are doing actually. Please [read a book](https://git-scm.com/book) first.

Comment: you can't send data to a subfolder of a git repository. You need to push the changes in the git repository itself .

Comment: then can you tell me how to do my task ? I need to put 2 projects in to different trees (or folders).One is Client and other is Server. @JimmyD

Comment: @Sampath Try `git add Client` then `git commit` to commit changes only in the `Client` folder.

Comment: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/17/git-svn-empty-directories/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot commit a folder on git, only files.  Git creates the folders for any files under version control.

The steps to commit to a **file** on git, is as follows:

1. Initialize a git repo, either an empty repo or clone an existing repo
2. Checkout the repo on your computer (you can directly add/edit files github website but this would be a prohibitive workflow for a working project)
3. Create the file you want to track changes on, e.g., `Client/<some file>` and `Server/<some file>`
4. Add these to the git tracking using `git add <filename>`
5. Commit the changes using `git commit -m "some commit message"` (if the message flag, `-m`, is left out you should be prompted to add a commit message)
6. Push changes to the server using `git push` (you need not push after every commit, just note that others cannot see your changes until after you push them to the server)

There are many great resources available to get started using Git.  [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com) provides a nice [Try Git](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-git) intro course for getting started with Git.  GitHub also provides a useful [Hello World](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/) guide for getting started with Git, though this requires first having Git installed (and maybe configured, I forget).  [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/?utm_source=learn-git&utm_medium=navigation&utm_campaign=learn-git) also some useful resources at no charge, a more extensive [video course](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/videos#episodes), an [on-line ebook](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/introduction), and cheat sheets on [Git commands](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/content/02-cheat-sheets/01-git/git-cheat-sheet-large01.png) and [Version Control Best Practices](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/content/02-cheat-sheets/01-git/git-cheat-sheet-large02.png). Another great resource is the book [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), written by Scott Chacon and Ben Straub and available under the [Creative Commons Attribution Non Commercial Share Alike 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the huge info :)